# How can I make my function work for any number?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having some issues with some code I wrote for this problem:

> “Write a function namedd calc that will evaluate a simple arithmetic expression. The input to your program will be a string of the form:
>   operand1 operator operand2
>   where operand1 and operand2 are non-negative integers and operator is a single-character operator, which is either +, -, or *. You may assume that there is a space between each operand and the operator. You may further assume that the input is a valid mathemat- ical expression, i.e. your program is not responsible for the case where the user enters gibberish.
>   Your function will return an integer, such that the returned value is equal to the value produced by applying the given operation to the given operands.
>   Sample execution:

```
calc("5 + 10") # 15
```

> “**You may not use the split or eval functions in your solution**.
>   Hint: the hard part here is breaking the input string into its three component. You may use the find and rfind functions to find the position of the first and last space, and then use the slice operator (that is, s[startindex:endindex]) to extract the relevant range of characters. Be careful of off-by-one errors in using the slice operator.
>   Hint: it’s best to test your code as you work. The first step should be to break the input string into its three components. Write a program that does that, have it print out the operator and the two operands on separate lines, and test it until you are convinced that it works. Then, modifying it to perform the desired mathematical operation should be straightforward. Test your program with several different inputs to make sure it works as you expect.”

Here is my code:

```
def calc(exp):
    operand1 = int(exp[:1])
    operand2 = int(exp[4:6])
    operator = exp[2:3]

    if(operator == "+"):
        addition = operand1+operand2
        return addition

   if(operator == "-"):
        subtraction = operand1-operand2
        return subtraction

   if(operator == "*"):
        multiplication = operand1*operand2
        return multiplication

print(calc("5 + 10"))
print(calc("4 - 8"))
print(calc("4 * 3"))
```

My code does not fully meet the criteria of this question. It only works for single digit numbers. How can I make my code work for any number?

Like:

```
“504 + 507”

”5678 + 76890”
```

and so on?

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The “Hint:” addresses this pretty directly.

Comment: Side-note: They forbid `split` and `eval`, but not `rsplit`, `partition` or `rpartition` which would all work just fine here. Just saying...

Comment: I have never heard of those as I am new to python, however, anything they did not go over in class, we cannot use or else its an automatic fail.

Comment: I know of some built in functions but I am used to using a lot of things that they said I cannot use lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the hint says, get the position of the first and last space of the expression, use it to extract the operand and the operators, and then evaluate accordingly.

```
def calc(exp):

    #Get the position for first space with find
    low_idx  = exp.find(' ')
    #Get the position for last space with rfind
    high_idx = exp.rfind(' ')

    #Extract operators and operand with slice, converting operands to int
    operand1 = int(exp[0:low_idx])
    operator = exp[low_idx+1:high_idx]
    operand2 = int(exp[high_idx:])
    result = 0

    #Evaluate based on operator
    if operator == '+':
        result = operand1 + operand2
    elif operator == '-':
        result = operand1 - operand2
    elif operator == '*':
        result = operand1 * operand2

    return result


print(calc("5 + 10"))
print(calc("4 - 8"))
print(calc("4 * 3"))
print(calc("504 + 507"))
print(calc("5678 + 76890"))
#15
#-4
#12
#1011
#82568
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take the string and use the split method for the string object, which will return a list of strings based on some separator.

For example:

```
stringList = "504 + 507".split(" ")
```

stringList will now be a list such as ["504", "+", "507"] due to the separator " " which is a whitespace. Then just use `stringList[1]` with your conditionals to solve the problem. Additionally, you can use int(stringList[0]) and int(stringList[2]) to convert the strings to int objects.

EDIT:
Now I realized that your problem said to use find() instead of split(). Simply use the logic above but instead find(" ") the first whitespace. You will then need to find the second whitespace by slicing past the first whitespace using the two additional arguments available for find().

Comment: The specification says *"You may not use the split or eval functions in your solution."* Which IMO is silly, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the specification:

> You may use the find and rfind functions to find the position of the first and last space, and then use the slice operator (that is, s[startindex:endindex]) to extract the relevant range of characters.

`find` and `rfind` are methods of string objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could split it into three components using this code: (note: this doesn't use split or eval)

```
def splitExpression(e):
    numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"] # list of all numbers
    operations = ["+","-","*","/"] # list of all operations
    output = [] # output components
    currentlyParsing = "number" # the component we're currently parsing
    buildstring = "" # temporary variable
    for c in e:
        if c == " ":
            continue # ignore whitespace
        if currentlyParsing == "number": # we are currently parsing a number
            if c in numbers:
                buildstring += c # this is a number, continue
            elif c in operations:
                output.append(buildstring) # this component has reached it's end
                buildstring = c
                currentlyParsing = "operation" # we are expecting an operation now
            else:
                pass # unknown symbol!
        elif currentlyParsing == "operation": # we are currently parsing an operation
            if c in operations:
                buildstring += c # this is an operation, continue
            elif c in numbers:
                output.append(buildstring) # this component has reached it's end
                buildstring = c
                currentlyParsing = "number" # we are expecting a number now
            else:
                pass # unknown symbol!

    if buildstring: # anything left in the buffer?
        output.append(buildstring)
        buildstring = ""
    return output
```

Usage: `splitExpression("281*14")` returns `["281","*","14"]`

This function also accepts spaces between numbers and operations

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string out instead of hard coding the positions of the indexes.
When coding you want to try to make your code as dynamic as possible, that generally means not hard coding stuff that could be a variable or in this case could be grabbed from the spaces.

Also in the if statements I modified them to elif as it is all one contained statement and thus should be grouped.

```
def calc(exp):
    vals = exp.split(' ')
    operand1 = int(vals[0])
    operand2 = int(vals[2])
    operator = vals[1]

    if operator == '+':
        return operand1+operand2
    elif operator == '-':
        return operand1-operand2
    else:
        return operand1*operand2
```

Comment: The specification says *"You may not use the split or eval functions in your solution."* Which IMO is silly, but that's beside the point.